# Is it possible to read data from a usb device without drivers on a mac?

Tags: macos, usb, hardware

I'm just trying to read raw bytes outputed by the device. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible. On Mac OSX, we can use the IOKitLib and IOUSBLib in user mode to read the data from usb device directly. There is a sample in Apple's developer website. You can refer to it https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000456

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no concept of "raw bytes" in the USB protocol. Unlike RS-232 communications (for example), USB communications always uses a high level protocol to control the communications between the device and the host.

A similar thing though, is to use a USB serial driver to read bytes sent over the USB serial device class protocol from the device. However, this requires specific support from the device.